# Nomodeset on intel boot with NVIDIA PRIME

Tags: nvidia, 15.10, nvidia-optimus

Using Ubuntu 15.10 on Kernel 4.2

I have installed the closed-source NVIDIA drivers for my optimus laptop and `nvidia-prime`. It works perfectly with one slight problem: **If I want to boot with intel graphics I need to add `nomodeset` to the boot line in GRUB**. NVIDIA works fine without it, actually it won't boot correctly with `nomodeset` (black screen).

Is there any way to boot with intel graphics without `nomodeset`? Or do I have to do this every time I switch with `prime-select`?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I had to install the latest intel graphics drivers using [this tool.](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.4.0)

Now I can boot fine without `nomodeset`.